# Why does $n \mid (x-1)\iff x=kn+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

It maybe trivial but I can convince myself, why is the following true?

$$n \mid (x-1)\iff x=kn+1$$

Or in the general case

$$n \mid (x-a)\iff x=kn+a:a\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition $n\mid(x-a)$ means there exists $k\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that $x-a=kn$. This is equivalent to $x=kn+a$.

Answer (score 2):

It is true, because by definition $n\mid (x-1)$ means that there exists a $k$ such that $kn=x-1$. The definition $n\mid m$ says that there is a $k$ such that $kn=m$. So the "general case" is just the definition, for different $m$'s.

Comment: Got it.
And because we are in a group there is an inverse for $1$ in this case and we can add $1$ to both sides?

Comment: Divisibility is meant here in the *ring* of integers. And yes, in the ring we can add $1$, for the additive group.